# Batch IF command not running

Tags: loops, for-loop, batch-file, if-statement

I'm trying to grab a couple of lines in some files and store them in variables (`line3` and `line4`).
Here is the code:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir *.md /b /o:-n /a:-d') do (
call :getLines "%%a"
)

pause
exit

:getLines
set /A cnt=2
for /f "skip=4 tokens=*" %%b in (%1) do (
set /A cnt+=1
set "line!cnt!=%%b"
if !cnt! == 4 (
    set "filename=%~n1"
    set "blogdate=!filename:~0,10!"
    set "blogtitle=!filename:~11!"
    echo hello
    echo !line3!
    echo !line4!
    echo !filename!
    echo !blogdate!
    echo !blogtitle!
)
)
goto :eof
```

The above will not even echo `hello`. I can't see what's wrong.
This is what each file looks like:

```
# Title

*2015-11-17*

Tags: word1 word2

First Sentence is here.
```

Filenames look like this:

```
2015-11-17-title.md
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `echo cnt is !cnt!` _before_ the if-statement?

Comment: That's why I'm here.

Comment: You should use back quotes on those iterations, as you've responsibly doublequoted the passed argument, i.e. `For /F "UseBackQ Skip=4 Tokens=*" %%b In (%1) Do (`

Comment: Additionally, your provided example `.md` content, shows your `Title` on line `1` and the intended new file BaseName italicized on line `3`, which in a standard `For /F` loop will be line `2`, _as empty lines are not processed_. In fact if you `skip` the first `4` lines, all of your provided content will be skipped. Can you please clarify exactly which lines your wanting to save to variables and whether the file content in your question is a true representation of the actual files. An overview of the actual task, instead of what you want the posted code to do would also help us to help you.

Comment: Yes, I understand for loop ignores blank lines, but the skip option does not. It's working good now.

Comment: To clarify what I meant, if your provided example is a true representation, `!line3!` will be `Tags: word1 word2` and `!line4!` will be `First Sentence is here.`. If those empty lines aren't really there, i.e. are due to an error in posting, all of the lines you've posted are skipped. As I've previously asked, can you please clarify exactly which lines your wanting to save to variables and whether the file content in your question is a true representation of the actual files. An overview of the actual task, instead of what you want the posted code to do would also help us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passed to call with quotes, so you should strip it first (or use `usebackq`).
Also when you are testing, don't use `exit` yet.
Try this, see if it works:
(Formatted so the structure is more clear, try comment `@echo off` to get more details.)

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir *.md /b /o:-n /a:-d') do (
    call :getLines "%%a"
)

pause
::exit
goto :eof

:getLines
set /A cnt=2
for /f "usebackq skip=4 tokens=*" %%b in (%1) do (
    set /A cnt+=1
    set "line!cnt!=%%b"
    if !cnt! == 4 (
        set "filename=%~n1"
        set "blogdate=!filename:~0,10!"
        set "blogtitle=!filename:~11!"
        echo hello
        echo !line3!
        echo !line4!
        echo !filename!
        echo !blogdate!
        echo !blogtitle!
        goto :eof
    )
)
goto :eof
```

`for` will take the input with quotes as string not as file.
`%~1` will strip `%1`'s quotes.
Check `for /?` and `call /?` for more details.

Comment: Correct, `%~1` will strip the surrounding doublequotes from `%1`, however, any filename containing spaces or potentially poison characters, will not work as intended. Please see my comment to find out how to fix that.

Comment: @Compo  Yeah, I was thinking the same way. And just updated my answer. Thanks :D

Comment: ok, working better. Still don't get echo's though. Should I not? Also I'm noticing that all lines in the files are parsed, even after line 4, so what's a good way to jump out of that loop after line 4?

Comment: I tried with your sample content and filename, and it's actually echoing.  Maybe give us more sample data? And the skip can use `goto :eof` inside I think. @tyee

Comment: Sure thing. @tyee